# How do you select a specific value from a list of data frames in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, extract

I have a list of data frames in R. In each data frame, the second row of the first column is a date. I want to loop through my list of data frames to select these start dates. I am able to select the date by doing

```
df[[2,1]]
```

However, when I try to loop through the list I am unable to do so. Here is what I have so far, but it prints each value as null.

```
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
 print(my_list$i[[2,1]])
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `my_list$i[[2,1]]` use `my_list[[i]][[2,1]]` or `my_list[[c(i,1,2)]]` to go true all data frame's in your list.

```
my_list <- list(data.frame(1:3, 4:6), data.frame(7:8, 9:10))

for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
 print(my_list[[i]][[2,1]])
 #print(my_list[[c(i,1,2)]]) #Alternative
}
#[1] 2
#[1] 8
```

Instead of a `for` loop you can use e.g. `sapply` with `[`:

```
sapply(my_list, "[", 2, 1)
#[1] 2 8
```